# Identify orange-brown, teardrop-shaped insect in central Europe that was found indoors

Tags: species-identification, entomology

TL;DR Can someone identify the species of the insect in below picture? Editing of the wording of this question (if possible) to make it easier to find by using search engines is welcome.

I caught this insect and was wondering what species it was:

[image]

Here a milimeter-scale and an USB-plug next to it to allow to estimate the size (sorry that they are so unsharp but I hope it is sufficient to get the size):

[image]
[image]

I was not able to find it by reverse image search or by searching for some keywords using google. I also checked some questions here but did not find any that seems to be about such an insect.

Following description/keywords are added to help someone searching for such an insect to find this using word-search. If someone can formulate this more search-engine-friendly to make this more likely to be found, please edit or add a comment so I can edit it:

- Teardrop-shaped
- six legs / 6 legs
- two antennas / 2 antennas
- orange-brown / brown-orange
- size about 3mm / 3 millimeters / 0.11811 in / 0.11811 inches (I hope my calculation from mm to in is correct)
- if touched by glas or paper, it remained motionless for about 1 to 2 minutes
- no wings / not airbourne / walking
- able to walk up walls
- it was found indoors
- the region is central Europe

Many Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For everyone who may be waiting for an answer to this or who at some point in the future find this through google: I have found the species fo the respective insect, it is Gibbium psylloides (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gibbium_psylloides).

Comment: Thank you for posting an answer to your own question. Please note that you are much more likely to get a positive response to your answer if you explain why your identification is correct. Specifically, please [edit] your answer to add discussion of key features that led you to this conclusion and supporting references or at least validated images. Without this your answer is indistinguishable from opinion. ——— Please consult the [help] pages for additional advice on [Answer] effectively on this site.

Answer (score -1):

I think it may have been a tick of some kind, one that had already fed and was round (hungry ticks are sort of flat).  I couldn't say exactly what species.

I'm not sure, but that's the only thing I can think of that matches this photo.  I'm no professional, so another person here may be able to do better.

Ticks have eight legs (they're vaguely related to mites, and, even more distantly, to spiders), so I was puzzled at first by you saying it had six legs, but possibly what you thought were its antennae were its other pair of legs?  (Ticks have no antennae).

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tick

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I see the similarity with tigs but I doubt this is a tick. For onc, I think it really had antennae because it moved them while walking instead of using them as legs. In addition, ticks would likely not remain motionless if touched because they have to grab prey walking past them when sitting in the gras. Also, ticks have their legs somehow streched out to the side, this one has them kind of V-shaped. I agree that from the general description this could be a tick so this answer may be good for someone else finding this through google. Please note that I did NOT downvote.

Comment: Fair enough!  Thanks for the comments, that makes sense.